# MySQL Node Mysql

Tags: node.js, mysql-connector

I tried out the create_database Code here https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs  /nodejs_mysql_create_db.asp
But I get the error-message "Object expected in Line 1 letter 1", what is this?
My code is this

```
  var mysql = require('mysql');

  var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "myusername",
  password: "mypassword"
  });

  con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query("CREATE DATABASE mydb", function (err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created");
  });
  });
```

What is erroneous, the code in the website of w3 schools, or my one?

Comment: Please reformat for readability, and minimize the example to verify that it's really complaining about that first line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your MYSQL server? Can you create the database manually?

What happens if you type in your terminal: `mysql -u yourusername -p`
Then enter your password, then type: `CREATE DATABASE mydb;`

To view your databases type: `show databases;`

Comment: I didn't setup any thing, because I don't know how.

Comment: My next question is where does the code I posted create the database? I need it on my webserver, not local

Comment: Your web server should be running a mysql service. If it is not then there is no point in trying to create a mysql database. Do you have shell access to your webserver? Can you find out if is has a database server running? The database will be created within the mysql server, the mysql server will provide access to it.

Comment: What happens if you type in your terminal: mysql -u yourusername -p Then enter your password, then type: CREATE DATABASE mydb;

To view your databases type: show databases; Terminal is the windows-cmd.exe ?

Comment: mysql the command could not found in my console.exe

Comment: Your web server should be running a mysql service. If it is not then there is no point in trying to create a mysql database. Do you have shell access to your webserver? Can you find out if is has a database server running? The database will be created within the mysql server, the mysql server will provide access to it. How do I know this?

Comment: I want to develop a booking-website for a hotel, so I need a database with a table containing all the rooms and another table with all the bookings. So my clients must get the access to the database and enter their booking. Perhaps for this purpose there is an easy way?

Comment: First problem is a new clien has neither a user name nor a password, never the less he should see which rooms there are. Possibly by enter something like "newuser" and "newpassword".

Comment: I must be sure that one and the same room is not more than once booked for the same time on the other hand I want to have all the hotel full.